# Use Only First "x" Characters from Table in qgis:selectbyexpression

Tags: pyqgis, select

I have a list of street names in this format:

```
STRNAME
Elsinore
Neil Young
Penny
Fall
```

And a shapefile ("input_streets") with street names in this format:

```
STREET
Elsinore Av
Neil Young St
Penny Lane
Fall Dr
```

I want to select streets in the "input_streets" shapefile that are also found in the 1st list, but you can see my challenge, the first list doesn't have the street suffixes, the second list does.  This means a simple expression like this won't work:

```
expression = '"STREET" = '+ "'"+ strname"'"
```

...where "strname" is just the "STRNAME" values from the first list.  The suffixes in "STREET" values 'get in the way'.

I need a way to give QGIS an expression that can compare ONLY the Street Names (their Prefixes, Ignoring the Suffixes, whatever they happen to be: St, Lane, Rd, etc.)

Something like:

```
street = STREET[0:firstspace]
```

But can this be done?  Can one refer to the column heading of a table with RESTRICTIONS on HOW MUCH of the column value to USE in an expression? (ie. "give me the value in STREET but stop at the first space")

Example:

```
street = STREET[0:firstspace]
expression = 'street = '+ "'"+ strname"'"
```

Or can one only refer to the column heading in an expression, and whatever values happen to be in that column, you're stuck with?

Comment: I would calculate in the shapefile with a python syntax ''.join(split(NameField," ")[-1:]) and join on that; It would probably be best to upcase or lowercase both fields though : Neil young != Neil Young.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Miles-Stimson, but can you explain further?  You're suggesting I perform a join between the list and the shapefile?  There are no common columns on which to do that.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm suggesting you make a common column.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an expression like this:

```
left( "STRNAME", strpos( "STREET", "STRNAME") )
```

[image: Result]